# Proof trees for simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

I need to state the type of the term

```
((λx : int. (x ≤ 1)) 2)
```

and prove it using a proof tree. I'm fairly certain that this is taking 2 as an input for `x`, then comparing 2 to 1 and returning a `boolean`. This means the type of the term would be `int → boolean`. I'm just not sure how to write  a proof tree for it. If someone could point me towards some examples or explain how to do a similar problem that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the simply typed lambda calculus extended with the datatypes `int` and `boolean`, the terms `_≤_`, `1` and `2`, and the typing derivation rules

```
--------------------------------
Γ ⊢ _≤_ : int → int → boolean

------------
Γ ⊢ 1 : int 

------------                
Γ ⊢ 2 : int
```

Using these, and the standard STLC typing rules, the type of your term is *not* `int → boolean`, rather, it is `boolean` as we will see below. Also, it β-reduces to `2 ≤ 1`, so that should show you quite easily that it is a `boolean`.

But now to the meat of it: the typing derivation tree:

```
{x : int} ⊢ _≤_ : int → int → boolean       {x : int} ⊢ x : int             
----------------------------------------------------------------
                     {x : int} ⊢ x ≤_ : int → boolean                 {x: int} ⊢ 1 : int
                     --------------------------------------------------------------------
                                      {x: int} ⊢ x ≤ 1 : boolean
```

To save on horizontal space, let's do the rest in a new tree:

```
{x: int} ⊢ x ≤ 1 : boolean
----------------------------------------
{} ⊢ (λx : int. (x ≤ 1) : int → boolean               {} ⊢ 2 : int
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                 {} ⊢ ((λx : int. (x ≤ 1)) 2) : boolean ∎
```